# Preventing Windows Forms DataGridView moving to next row on pressing ENTER key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I know this question (or variants of it) has come up a few times.  But So far I have not found a solution that works for me.

I'm writing a Windows Forms UserControl using C# containing a DataGridView to present a read-only collection of employee data as a kind of glorified select list. The grid is read-only (populated on control_load) and has FullRowSelect  set as the selection method.  I want the user to be able either double mouse click or use the Enter Key on the current row to select an Id value form that row which gets picked up by subscribers to handle elsewhere.

In handling the KeyDown event after assigning my selected employee value, I attempt to prevent selection moving to the next row.  This works fine **except** when the CurrentCell.RowIndex is zero.
Does anyone know how I can get this working for CurrentCell.Rowindex = 0  ?

```
private void dgvEmployees_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            this.SelectedEmployeeId = (int) dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
            this.OnEmployeeSelected(new TestEmployeeGridListEventArgs() { 
            SelectedEmployeeId = this.SelectedEmployeeId, 
            SelectedEmployeeIdentifier = dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells["Identifier"].Value.ToString() 
            });
        }

        // Prevent pressing <enter key> moving onto the next row.
        if (dgvEmployees.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
        { 
            dgvEmployees.CurrentCell = dgvEmployees[1, dgvEmployees.CurrentCell.RowIndex - 1];
            dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            dgvEmployees.CurrentCell = dgvEmployees[1, 0];
            dgvEmployees.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `e.Handled = true;` or `e.SuppressKeyPress`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  Setting e.Handled or SuppressKeyPress to  true in the else block gives me exactly the behaviour I was looking for.  Many thanks.

Comment: You can use it instead of all `if` statement code block

Comment: Of course!  Much neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Reniuz fo the heads up.  All I needed was either to set `e.Handled = true` or `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` replacing the `if (dgvEmployees.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)` statement in it's entirety.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null)
    {
        this.SelectedEmployeeId = (int) dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        this.OnEmployeeSelected(new TestEmployeeGridListEventArgs() { 
            SelectedEmployeeId = this.SelectedEmployeeId, 
            SelectedEmployeeIdentifier = dgvEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells["Identifier"].Value.ToString() 
        });
    }

    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This....Its Perfectly Working In DatagridView CellEdit Event to enter then focus next cell not row.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)

 {

 // Check if Enter is pressed //  DGV Cell Edit // dgv1 as DataGrideView

 if (keyData == Keys.Enter /* && txtledger.Text != "" */)
 {

 try       
{

   if (dgv1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 18 ) 

// 18 is Column Count and focusing length

       {                       

        dgv1.CurrentCell = dgv1.Rows[dgv1.CurrentRow.Index + 1 ].Cells[1];
        return true;
       }
       else
       {
        SendKeys.Send("{Right}");  //Tab OR Right Key Ur Need
       }
     }
  catch (Exception e)

  {                    

  dgv1.Rows.Add();
  dgv1.CurrentCell = dgv1.Rows[dgv1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1];

  }

  return true;

  }

  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

  }
```

This will be working fine.. it is disable the normal enter key process inside the datagridview to work cell edit event to focus next cell in same row. If any problem check all keydown event in u r form...