# Visual Basic - Enter to Perform DataGridView CellContentClick

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, basic

First i would like to potentially apologise as i am new to Visual Basic (self taught) so some of my code may look odd.

I load a DataGridView with information populated by a SELECT Statement, when i click on a certain cell within the view it loads a new form which is fine. However i would like to know if there is a way in which i can change from a click to a key press of "ENTER".

I have attached my code, hopefully this helps.

thank you in Advance

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then ' not sure on code here
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If Update_Detail.Visible = True Then Update_Detail.Close()
    Dim istat As Object
    If e.RowIndex > -1 Then istat = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    If e.ColumnIndex < 1 And e.RowIndex > -1 Then Update_Detail.TextBox1.Text = istat
    If e.ColumnIndex < 1 And e.RowIndex > -1 Then Update_Detail.Show()
End Sub
```

Also I am using Visual Studio 2015 with .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: If you are using `vb.net` then there is no need to also include a `VBA` tag.

Comment: thank you - This has been removed.

Comment: There is a Key_Down event on the grid. You could use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            Dim currentColumnIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex


            Dim istat As Object

            If currentRowIndex > -1 Then istat = DataGridView1.Rows(currentRowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            If currentColumnIndex < 1 And currentRowIndex > -1 Then Update_Detail.TextBox1.Text = istat
            If currentColumnIndex < 1 And currentRowIndex > -1 Then Update_Detail.Show()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - That is brilliant works a treat. One other thing though - When i am pressing enter it is keeping the function of going to the row down also. Are you aware of the ability to turn this off?

Comment: No  problem. See here for potential solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096968/preventing-windows-forms-datagridview-moving-to-next-row-on-pressing-enter-key. You could try adding. `e.SupressKeyPress = True` at the end. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Again that has worked a treat. Thank you VERY much for that :)

Comment: Nice one and good luck. Almost always a solution to everything. :o)