# Set the current cell (DataGridView) according to a customize Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner with C # and I have created a personalized dialog (see Picture below). This is used to verify if the user wants to write a value on the CNC machine, which is entered through a DataGridView cell. At that moment, I am trying, if the user presses "Nein" the cursor must stay in the same cell where it was before, otherwise the cursor must jump to the next row. To do this, use the code shown below, but unfortunately it does not work, it always jump to the next row when Ja or Nein is pressed. I would appreciate if you could help me, because I'm out of ideas.

[image]

```
private void parameterWrite(){   

    if (CustomMsgBox.Show("Parameter zu CNC-Maschine", "Diesen Parameter an die CNC-Maschine senden?") == DialogResult.Yes ){
         //do something 
    }
    else{
         //j = row index
         if (j == 0){
              dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
              dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
         }
         else {
              dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
              dataGridView1.Rows[j-1].Cells[1].Selected = true;
         }
         dataGridView1.Rows[j].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
         dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
         dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which event is this code? Might be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26096968/1997232).

Comment: show the code for the custom dialog box please

Comment: Put a stop debugger on the parameterWrite line and run your program.  Watch the values as you step through the code.